# Article content submission form on Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selection, contact-form, formbuilder

I faced with the following problem:
it is need to realize on one Bootstrap-based site the possibility to receiving text content from users via contact form. I found the tool http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/. It seems perfect. But in accordance with my idea of contact form, the reporter shall select at first the necessary title of his message (e.g. "report" or "idea" or "claim" etc - this title shall be selected in the "select basic" element). Different titles shall contain different groups of input elements.

So, how can be realized such model, when the reporter at first shall select need title and after this selection the need group of input elements will automatically appear?

Answer (score 0):

**1st way:**

Create a contact form with all the input elements and use Javascript and CSS to hide the elements in base of the selection element. You can use a default option and when someone load for the first time the page, then all the other elements will be hided with javascript and if he choose another category, then you will hide these and unhide the other group.

**2nd way:**

If you don't want to play with CSS then you can load a default group and each time a user change the option from selection element, you can use Ajax to update the html content of the input form.

Comment: I suppose the second way will be more easy for me. Thanks for the ideas. I'll try to do it in this way.